# Load remote site into div

Tags: html, iframe

I'm try found iframe analog, I want load external page in my `div` if I using iframe IE blocking cookies, so I can't use iframe.

Comment: You can't typically do this, due to cross-origin blocking.  Also, what does this have to do with cookies?  Try telling us what you need to do, rather than looking for some crazy way to do it.

Comment: to:Brand ie blocing cookies I can't log to page

Comment: @TomasLietuva I'm from LT as well if you want you can write me to email, i could help you with this and other issues as well.

Comment: @Linas ok, but I don't know your email

Comment: @TomasLietuva It's in my profile page.

Comment: @Linas bro that email only you can see ;)

Comment: @TomasLietuva Huh, that's quite stupid, either way it's `shinigamiworks@gmail.com`